# Use aggregate values for farther calculation

Tags: mysql

I have the followin query:

```
SELECT contracts.id,
  (SELECT sum(pos.sum_to_pay) FROM pos
    where pos.contract_id=contracts.id and pos.is_draft=0) as paid,
  (SELECT sum(acts.amount) FROM acts
    where acts.contract_id=contracts.id) as acts_sum
from contracts
```

it works but i want to add another result field `to_pay` that should be calculated like `acts_sum - paid = to_pay`.

I'm trying to do it like this:

```
 SELECT contracts.id,
      (SELECT sum(pos.sum_to_pay) FROM pos
        where pos.contract_id=contracts.id and pos.is_draft=0) as paid,
      (SELECT sum(acts.amount) FROM acts
        where acts.contract_id=contracts.id) as acts_sum,
      (acts_sum - paid) as to_pay 
    from contracts
```

but I got the error `Unknown column 'acts_sum'`. How can i find `to_pay` value based on `acts_sum` and `paid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with a subquery like this

```
SELECT acts_sum, paid, (acts_sum - paid) as to_pay FROM
(SELECT contracts.id,
  (SELECT sum(pos.sum_to_pay) FROM pos
    where pos.contract_id=contracts.id and pos.is_draft=0) as paid,
  (SELECT sum(acts.amount) FROM acts
    where acts.contract_id=contracts.id) as acts_sum,
from contracts ) subq
```

Comment: Yeah, too slow again ;-) @Xing said it already (although: his subquery seems to be lacking a name).

Comment: @AndriyLozynskiy Does the solution provided by me didnot work ?

Comment: @XING It doesn't work without alias for subquery. I got error `Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: @AndriyLozynskiy Good to know. In Oracle however its not madatory to alias a subquery. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite your query using joins, correlated sub queries sometimes considered as a costly solution

```
select c.id,
COALESCE(a.acts_sum,0),
COALESCE(p.paid,0),
COALESCE(a.acts_sum,0) - COALESCE(p.paid,0) as to_pay 
from contracts c
left join (
    SELECT contract_id,sum(sum_to_pay) paid
    FROM pos
    where is_draft=0
    group by contract_id
) p on c.id = p.contract_id 
left join (
    SELECT contract_id,sum(amount) acts_sum
    FROM acts
    group by contract_id
) a on c.id = a.contract_id
```